# how to add empty fxml with a fmxlcontroller.java in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, javafx

I tried to make a new fxml page and it was sucess. But  unable to find any java class file related that fxml.. but in netbeans if we open an empty fxml file it is getting with a class but in eclipse it is not getting .. is there any solution for it ?

Comment: This question is very unclear. Can you clarify what you mean? Are you asking about creating a controller class?

Comment: yes .. how to add new control class for new fxml file

Comment: Just create a new class in the usual way, and add the `fx:controller` attribute to the root element. There is nothing particularly special about the controller class; it is just a plain old regular Java class. I don't think there is a FXML-specific way to do this in Eclipse.

Comment: as u are telling that call as fxmlloader load,getclass method right?

Comment: I don't understand what that has to do with the controller.

Comment: in same fxml controller java file will be take too much codes for reg. , login etc. so I was expected to create new fxml file and a new class for reg..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155269/discussion-between-vivek-and-james-d).

Answer (score 0):

create  a new class ( save class name ) and open fxml file with scene builder . In scene builder go to controllers there is dropdown list of names with the class name choose that class which u want save it ... and enter the code in class and run the application.